# r - difficulty apply()ing a filter() to a data.frame

Tags: r, filter, apply

Good Morning,

I am having some difficulty finding a solution to this:

My data frame has several thousand entities (columns) ranked (values) over time (rows):

```
Year Entity1 Entity2 ... EntityN
2001   1302     36    ...   1
2002    2       576   ...  1101
```

I am trying to find a way to output a new data frame with only the top 3 ranked Entities for a year, if possible, with the Entity names as values and the ranks as column names.

I have been playing with something like this, but to no avail:

```
library(dplyr)
newdf <- apply(mydata, 1, function(x) filter(x, values > 3)
```

If anyone has any insight, it would be very welcome!

Comment: `dplyr::filter` takes a `data.frame` as input, but the apply function converts each row to a numeric vector. Try: `apply(mydata, 1, function(x) names(x)[x>3])`

Comment: `apply(mydata, 1, function(x) names(x)[x<4])` works a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer:
`dplyr::filter` takes a data.frame as input, but the `apply` function converts each row to a numeric vector. Try:

```
apply(mydata, 1, function(x) names(x)[x>3])
```